# Quickly access point in UI

Tags: angularjs, protractor

We have quite and extensive wizard UI flow and in order to test development changes (e.g.: DOM chanes) at the end of the flow we need to go through all the steps every time since there is data dependancy gathered in previous steps.

This is tedious, takes a lot of time, every time.

Have been thinking about some way of defaulting data but then still we have to click some buttons to get some a-ync data based on the input and press the next btn in the wizard steps.

Using a protractor like behaviour would be excellent. We already have tests set up for that which can take us to the point we need to verify, while developing, in seconds and having all the (stubbed) data in there.

Like to hear your thoughts on this and if such an automated Protractor way of getting to a certain point is possible.

EDIT: why not just use the Protractor test we use on the test server to use locally to go through the development steps and let it stop at a certain point?

Comment: I think you answered your own question by the end of it.  Why not just use Protractor?  Did you try it?  Did it work?  StackOverflow is meant for answering the questions you have once you try something specific (not so much for figuring out what to try).

Comment: Wasnt able to test it yet, but the PT approach should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing the post and re-reading it I answered it in the EDIT with Protractor. Havent tried it yet but should do the trick.